Web site certificate
I have bought a certificate for my local iis web site .
I have generated a csr online with a csr generator.
The ceritificate will be issue shortly.
I want to know if this certificate will run with my local iis web site.

If you add it to your pages, yes it will.

…sure, why wouldn't it? Perhaps you could clarify your doubts. // Also, next time, maybe ask before buying a certificate. Depending on the circumstances, Let's Encrypt might have bern an option.
